# Hahnel remote fires Canon 5DMk2 + Elinchrom lights, but how to simultaneously fire a Mamiya RZ?

Tags: canon-5d-mark-ii, mamiya, sync, elinchrom

I have a set-up where I'm able to use a Hahnel Captur flash remote to fire my Canon 5D Mark 2 which is connected to my Elinchrom lights...But, I'd also like to simultaneously fire my Mamiya RZ.

I can touch the RZ, I don't need to be away from it. But, as it's triggered manually, how can I sync it so that when I press the Mamiya, it also fires the Canon/Elinchrom lights?

Answer (score 2):

Can't use use the same hardware? The RZ should have a flash port, which means you could put another transmitter on it. The sync (if it's a full blade or curtain, I don't know which you have) you'll have to use the right port. I thought older models had an X-Sync as well as a.... I forget the name. But typically there were two ports. So a flash hot sync cable should do it and let you slave everything together.

Comment: I should say I used to tie multiple cameras and strobes together to shoot sporting events. A single button on my vest would trigger two remote cameras and 4 strobes mounted up in the rafters/ stands. The biggest issue was RF interference, so in some cases we ran power cords to use AC blades. Our largest concern was someone would find one and plug it into an AC outlet thus frying cameras. Thus everything was 'tagged' and 'zip tied' together so that couldn't happen.